# Execution failed for task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig' while running Flutter app on my mobile phone

Tags: flutter, gradle

While trying to run my flutter app on my phone in debug mode, [I received this exception in the debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKbOW.png) and the execution failed consequently. Is there any way to deal with this build failure?

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `build` floder from your project and try it agin. Hope it will work.

or

Only need to add the following code on the `build.gradle` file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'androidx.media:media:1.0.0'
    }
```

}

Comment: There is two `build.gradle` files in the flutter app folder. Are you talking about `./android/app/build.gradle` file or `./android/build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to android> gradle-wrapper.properties.
2. Change gradle version.(for me gradle version 6.5 and 6.3 works fine) [go here to see gradle versions](https://gradle.org/releases/)
3. From terminal, type

   > cd android

   > gradlew

[image]

3. Run Flutter clean and Run

Comment: Modifying the gradle version and then executing the `flutter clean` command downgraded several important flutter packages, which raised quite a lot of new errors. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Use flutter pub get and pub upgrade after running flutter clean

Comment: It is still showing error

Comment: After updating gradle version, go to android folder( cd android) and run gradlew command